# convert a pointer to an instance of a class in cython

Tags: c, arrays, class, pointers, cython

I have written a class in cython and I have a method that would check if there is no attribute to a class object or not. It would either read this object from a file in the case the file exists or it calculates the valuse which is an array or a memoryview and saves the results in a file. the following is partial part of my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libc.stdio cimport FILE, fopen, fwrite, fscanf, fclose, stdout, stderr

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double exp(double) nogil
    double log(double) nogil

cdef class NFW(object):
    cdef object ks, source_redshift
    cdef const char* path
    def __cinit__(self, char* path, double[::1] zs=None, *args):
        self.path=path
        if self.path==NULL:
           raise ValueError("Could not find a path to the file which contains the table of  diameter distances")
        if zs is None:
           raise ValueError("You must give an array !")
        self.source_redshift=zs

    @cython.cdivision(True)    
    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    cdef void get_ks(self):
         cdef FILE* handle
         cdef Py_ssize_t i, nz
         nz  = len(self.source_redshift)
         cdef double* array[nz] 
         if not hasattr(self, 'ks'):  # does self.ks not exist?
            try:
               ## first, check for existing file, see if we can load in self.ks
               handle = fopen(self.path, "r")
               if handle == NULL:
                  raise ValueError("cannot open file {}".format(self.path))

               for i from nz > i >= 0:
                   fscanf(handle,"%f",&array[i])
               fclose(handle)
               self.ks= &array
            except IOError:

               self.ks = self.calculate_ks() 

    @cython.cdivision(True)    
    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    cdef double[::1] calculate_ks(self):
         cdef Py_ssize_t i, nz
         nz  = len(self.source_redshift)
         cdef double[::1] k_s = np.zeros(nz,dtype=np.float64_t)

         for i from nz > i >= 0:         
             k_s[i]= log((1.+self.source_redshift[i])/(1.-self.source_redshift[i]))
         #write the calculated k_s in a file
         cdef FILE* handle=<FILE *>fopen(self.path,"wb")
         fwrite(k_s,sizeof(k_s),1,handle)
         fclose(handle)
         return k_s
```

I am not very familiar with c and I am a cython beginner. I have gotten the following error messages and I don't know how is the best way to read a file in cython in a pointer array and convert it into an instance of a class. I should stress I am looking for the fastest way to carry out a file reading in cython.

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    cdef void get_ks(self):
         cdef FILE* handle
         cdef Py_ssize_t i, nz
         nz  = len(self.source_redshift)
         cdef double* array[nz] 
                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

WLUtilities.pyx:413:30: Not allowed in a constant expression

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
                  raise ValueError("cannot open file {}".format(self.path))

               for i from nz > i >= 0:
                   fscanf(handle,"%f",&array[i])
               fclose(handle)
               self.ks= &array
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

WLUtilities.pyx:424:24: Cannot convert 'double *(*)[__pyx_v_nz]' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
         k_s = np.zeros(nz,dtype=np.float64_t)
         for i from nz > i >= 0:         
             k_s[i]= self.__ks(self.source_redshift[i])
         #write the calculated k_s in a file
         cdef FILE* handle=<FILE *>fopen(self.path,"wb")
         fwrite(k_s,sizeof(k_s),1,handle)
                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------


WLUtilities.pyx:440:19: Cannot convert Python object to 'const void *'
```

Answer (score 2):

(I apologize if this code has some small bugs and doesn't quite work right off - I haven't actually tested this. However the principle should work fine.)

Your easiest thing is not to use a double array, but to use a MemoryView. The overhead in accessing the elements is pretty low (not a great deal worse than a pointer access, and unlikely to be the limiting factor when doing IO). With a MemoryView you can use all the standard python methods for allocating memory painlessly at runtime.

Code is below, with a few notes as comments

```
# omitted "cdivision" - you aren't actually doing any division so it doesn't matter
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef void get_ks(self):
     cdef FILE* handle
     cdef Py_ssize_t i, nz
     nz  = len(self.source_redshift)
     # Memory is managed by numpy. Alternatively you can use the python array module
     # The "1" in "::1" promises that it's genuinely continuous (I think) and so should speed things up
     cdef double[::1] array = np.empty((nz,))
     if not hasattr(self, 'ks'):  # does self.ks not exist?
        try:
           ## first, check for existing file, see if we can load in self.ks
           handle = fopen(self.path, "r")
           if handle == NULL:
              raise ValueError("cannot open file {}".format(self.path))

           # I've changed this to "range" because it's a little more iomatic
           # change it back if you like! It shouldn't make much difference
           for i in range(nz-1,-1,-1):
               # &array[i] should still work with a memoryview
               # Changed to 'lf' since we're using doubles
               fscanf(handle,"%lf",&array[i])
           fclose(handle) # does this want to be in "finally" to ensure it gets done?
           self.ks= array # no need to take address - this should just work
        except IOError:

           self.ks = self.calculate_ks()
```

The error in "calculate_ks" can probably be dealt with as

```
cdef double* array_as_doubles = &ks[0]
fwrite(<void*>array_as_doubles, # cast to void
       sizeof(double),len(ks), # calculate length properly! 
       handle)
```

As a final note - if you really want to manage the memory yourself you can use the C malloc/free functions to give you a double array (see http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html). However, you are entirely responsible for making sure it gets freed at an appropriate time, which you probably don't want to get into.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
         nz  = len(self.source_redshift)
         cdef double* array[nz] 
                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

WLUtilities.pyx:413:30: Not allowed in a constant expression
```

Since you call len on a python object, it is not clear that nz will be known at compile time, that's why Cython complains here.
Something like:

```
     cdef double* array[5]
```

Will compile (of course this is useless for you as it is, but the point is that you have to get nz to be known at compile time, maybe using a c function to get the size).
Here:

```
              self.ks= &array
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

WLUtilities.pyx:424:24: Cannot convert 'double *(*)[__pyx_v_nz]' to Python object
```

You cannot assign an adress to a Python object. Something like this dereferences the adress and casts its content to something cython will be able to handle:

```
       self.ks= np.array(<double[:5]> array[0])
```

(Again, the 5 should be replaced by your nz that must be known at constant time). You might want to cast it to something else, the point is that you have to turn it into something that is not an adress when putting it into a Python object.

Here:

```
         fwrite(k_s,sizeof(k_s),1,handle)
                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------


WLUtilities.pyx:440:19: Cannot convert Python object to 'const void *'
```

You should just cast your memoryview to a void ponter (the syntax is perhaps annoying but it is what cython uses):

```
 fwrite(<void*> &k_s[0],sizeof(k_s),1,handle)
```

If you replace the lines in your code with these one above, the it will compile. Then again, you have to make nz to be known at compile time (you can use the "5" in the code just for testing). And there are several ways to cast using cython, these were some that came up to me, but you might find better ones.

Comment: It seems the problem is that I can not declare an array with a **dynamical size ** but since  I don't know the value of `nz` priory, I am afraid what you have explained could not be the good solution.

Comment: It was not the only problem - you had some casting issues. To adress them I continued with an arbitrary nz. But for statically know the nz, you could define a c function to get the array size and then cimporting it. The common ```sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0])```, for example.

Comment: Is it possible to use dynamical memory allocation ? My `C` knowledge is very limited.

Comment: Perhaps your best shot is cimporting the vector library from C++ (scroll down here and they show a little wrapper for it: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html). It is a template so maybe at first is a litle annoying to get the syntax (if you do not come from C++) but the advantage is that it feels more like Python (dynamic resizing, you have a .size() method...).
If you dont want to use a library, there always are the new and delete